# In Ubuntu, why does the menu bar and title scaling reset when my screen is detected?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 on a Lenovo ThinkStation P710 with an NVidia Quadro M2000 (using NVidia driver 375.66) graphics card and an LG 27UD88-W Ultra-HD 4K monitor.

With a high-resolution monitor like that, I need to adjust the scaling of title bars and menus to about 1.5 for anything to be usable. Doing this through the "Display" control panel works well.

However, whenever my monitor goes to sleep and then I wake it up again, some sort of screen detection takes place and suddenly the scale gets reset to 1.

So, for example, if I lock my computer and walk away, when I come back and wake up the monitor by moving the mouse, the screen turns on and the  contents of the login screen are correctly scaled to 1.5. However, after about 1~2 seconds, it suddenly drops to scale 1 and everything is minuscule again.

I'm new to using Linux on the desktop so I don't even know where to start looking for the rogue process that is resetting the scale factor when it detects the screen.

Comment: This has begun happening to me with Ubuntu 16.04. Did you find a solution, @brianskold?

Answer (score 3):

The bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1689356). It affects 17.04 and 16.04. No solution yet, but someone has released a patch [here](https://launchpad.net/~arter97/+archive/ubuntu/unity), which worked for me.